# Invalid use of Propensity Score Matching?

Tags: causality, propensity-scores, treatment-effect, causalimpact

I wonder if using a propensity score in the following situation is wrong. Imagine I have the next causal model

$$X = N_x$$
$$Y = f(X, N_y)$$
$$ Z = g(X, Y, N_z)$$
Where $N_z, N_y,  N_x$ are independent random variables. One example of such a model is $X$ is race, $Y$ is education $Z$ is income. If I wanted to estimate the causal effect of race on income, for example via ATE, would it be wrong to use propensity score matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to assume this particular causal model, then you don't need to use propensity score matching, or any other backdoor path related method, because the effect of $X$ on $Z$ is not confounded.

See the following from http://www.dagitty.net/:

[image]

Before you go and compute the effect of $X$ on $Z$ in this model though, you should probably consider a model with a different structure. Are you sure you're willing to assume this particular model? For example, are you sure there are no structural factors that affect both the demographics of an area and the income of the people in it?

If you were to imagine such a confounder, you would need to control for it in order to understand the effect of $X$ on $Z$:

[image]

If you think such a model is true, then propensity score matching on $C$ would make sense.

Comment: Ok, this makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it was helpful! If you felt that it answered your question, accepting it will make it easier for others with the same question to find.